# not able to get values in client side custom validation function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-validation

I am doing client side custom validations using jQuery, I am stuck in getting values from 
server side to do operations on client side ....
this is my server side custom validation function

```
public class SelctedValueCheckAttribute : ValidationAttribute , IClientValidatable
{
    public SelctedValueCheckAttribute(string otherProperty): base("{0} is not in correct range")
    {
        OtherProperty = otherProperty;
    }
    public string OtherProperty { get; set; }
    public SelctedValueCheckAttribute()
    {
        ErrorMessage = "Values must be in the Given Range";
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return "The Entered Value Must be in given range for " + name + "item";
    }
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object firstValue, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        string selecetdItemValue = firstValue as string ;
        string userEnteredValue = GetSecondValue(validationContext);
        if( string.Equals(selecetdItemValue, "Amount"))
        {
             int entry = Convert.ToInt32(userEnteredValue);
             if (entry < 10 || entry > 20)
             {
                 return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
             }                                
        }
        else if (string.Equals(selecetdItemValue, "Pound"))
        {
            int entry = Convert.ToInt32(userEnteredValue);
            if (entry < 80 || entry > 90)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
            }
        }
        else if (string.Equals(selecetdItemValue, "Percent"))
        {
            int entry = Convert.ToInt32(userEnteredValue);
            if (entry < 50 || entry > 60)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
            }
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
    protected string GetSecondValue(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
      var propertyInfo = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(OtherProperty);
      if (propertyInfo != null)
      {
       var secondValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);
       return secondValue as string;
      }
      return null;
   }               
   public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        ModelClientValidationRule mcvr = new ModelClientValidationRule();
        mcvr.ValidationType = "enteredvaluescheck";
        mcvr.ErrorMessage = "Selected Value must be in given range";
        mcvr.ValidationParameters.Add("other", OtherProperty);
        mcvr.ValidationType = "selectedvaluewithenteredvaluecheck";
        yield return mcvr;
    }
}
```

and this is my client side custom validation

```
           jquery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addSingleval("selectedvaluewithenteredvaluecheck",  "other");
jQuery.validator.addMethod("selectedvaluewithenteredvaluecheck",
                           function(val,element,other)
                           {
                               if(val & other)
                               {
                                 // here I am not getting the values..
                                 //do I need to write any function to get the values
                                //is there any other approach that I need to follow
                               }
```

How can I get the values in client side function?
Would any one have any idea about this and any suggestions please suggest me.

Comment: would you pls let me know if this is unclear ....

Comment: Take a look here. Theres something to do at client side: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/301022/Creating-Custom-Validation-Attribute-in-MVC-3

Answer (score 0):

You miss-spelled `jquery` and `addSingleval`. They should be capitalized `Q` and `V`.

```
jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addSingleVal("selectedvaluewithenteredvaluecheck",  "other");
```

Comment: Without fixing the code, you will not be able to see the data inside. Javascript is case-sensitive. Let's isolate problem one by one.

Comment: thanks .. i have done that but i don't know how to check whether this function(client side custom validation) is working or not ....would you pl tell how can I check ..

Comment: in `function(val,element,other)' you can try `console.log(val)` to see whether it will be printed in browser's console.

Comment: i am getting this error when i run on internet explorer Unhandled exception at line 2, column 1 in http://localhost:564/Scripts/mycustomvalidations.js

0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'jQuery.validator.unobtrusive' is null or not an object     I have written client side validations in seperate js file ...